# I have created a function which recursively creates a DOM-tree. Is it a good idea to use something like this in my project?

Tags: javascript

Example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qoejz4f/16/

This function  returns a tree of DIV-elements. it accepts the following parameters:

`param`: if typeof param is `"string"`, then this string is assigned as an ID of the element. If typeof param is `"number"` then this number of identical copies of the element are created without ID. Else just 1 element without ID is created.

`classList`: defines the classList of the element

`...children`: is an array of arguments, where every item is an array of `[param, classList, ...children]` arguments. For every item in `...children` a new child is created and appended to the current parent.

The function:

```
  grid: function(param, classList, ...children) {


    let element = document.createElement("div")
    if (typeof param == "string") {
      element.id = param
    };
    if (classList) {
      element.classList = classList
    };

    if (children.length > 0) {

      for (let j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {

        if (typeof children[j] == "function") {
          element.appendChild(children[j]());
        } else {
          if (typeof children[j][0] == "number") {
            for (let n = 0; n < children[j][0]; n++) {
              element.appendChild(this.grid(...children[j]));
            }
          } else {
            element.appendChild(this.grid(...children[j]));
          }
        }
      };
    }
    return element;
  }
```

Comment: Well if you don't need reference of each element then you can simply create html template use it instead of this function because using template is more efficient than creating element each time.

Comment: This question is more ontopc on programmers.stackexchange or codeview.stackexchange. ]\

Comment: @ajit kumar In my example I wanted `#mainMenu` (on the left) to be the same every time and `#legalDocument` to be changable, for example. And implement adding other DOM-elements like `select`, `input`, `span` with predetermined properties right into the function.