# How do I dynamically append html snippets into the web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
  <div id="mainMenu">

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

     <div class="giver">
      <hr class = "giver-hr">
      <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
      <select class ="giver-status"></select>
      <label class = giver-isClient>
        <input type = "radio">
        <span>lorem ipsum</span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="legalDocument"></div>
</div>
```

, where the `<div class="giver">` element is repeated multiple (9) times.

What is the best way to append such blocks dynamically, through `for(){}` cycle for example? The `innerHtml` property is not recommended from what I've heard. and using [a special recursive function that I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303431/i-have-created-a-function-which-recursively-creates-a-dom-tree-is-it-a-good-ide) doesn't seem to be the right way either.

What should I do? I'd like to extend my Web pages with templates kinda like how Javascript `class`es behave.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
const giver = `
  <div class="giver">
     <hr class = "giver-hr">
     <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
     <select class ="giver-status"></select>
     <label class = giver-isClient>
       <input type = "radio">
       <span>lorem ipsum</span>
     </label>
  </div>
`;

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  document.getElementById("mainMenu").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", giver);
}
```

Comment: Is it a "legit" method people use or is it more like proof of concept?

Comment: This will induce HTML parsing exactly as many times as `insertAdjacentHTML` is called, given how the method is provided source code, even though the latter may be the same as one of prior calls.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov yes, it is a "legit" method

Answer (score 3):

I'd use HTML [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) -- that's what they're for:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <template id="giver-template">
            <div class="giver">
                <hr class = "giver-hr">
                <select class ="giver-subject"></select>
                <select class ="giver-status"></select>
                <label class = giver-isClient>
                    <input type = "radio">
                    <span>lorem ipsum</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </template>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- document body -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The contents of a template, a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), are available through accessing the `content` property on the template element itself; these contents, being a `DocumentFragment`, are in a convenient form, parsed and ready, and will not incur extra overhead the way `innerHtml` or `insertAdjacentHTML` would imply because of need to parse the markup and produce DOM objects for insertion into the document.

As you can observe, `template` elements are contained in the document `head` section, meaning they are not themselves rendered or are part of your document body otherwise -- their utility lies in being able to clone them and use their "instantiated" copies.

You can trivially use the template defined above for your use-case:

```
const new_giver_element = document.getElementById("giver-template").content.cloneNode(true);
```

Meaning that `new_giver_element` now refers to a new, unattached DOM node (a `DocumentFragment`) (which you can further modify if you so wish) ready for insertion into a document through `appendChild` or other methods.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[see demo - stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sfzdfp)

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="legalDocument">
    </div>
</div>

var wrapper = document.querySelector("#mainMenu");
for(let i=0; i<9; i++) {
    wrapper.appendChild(createBox());
}

function createBox() {
  const giver  = document.createElement("div");
  giver.className = 'giver'
  const givenHr  = document.createElement("hr");
  givenHr.className = 'giver-hr'
  const giverSubject  = document.createElement("select");
  giverSubject.className = 'giver-subject'
  const giverStatus  = document.createElement("select");
  giverStatus.className = 'giver-status'
  const giverIsClient  = document.createElement("label");
  giverStatus.className = 'giver-isClient'
  const input  = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = 'radio'
  const span  = document.createElement("span");
  const text = document.createTextNode('lorem ipsum');

  span.appendChild(text);
  giverIsClient.appendChild(input);
  giverIsClient.appendChild(span);

  giver.appendChild(givenHr);
  giver.appendChild(giverSubject);
  giver.appendChild(giverStatus);
  giver.appendChild(giverIsClient);

  return giver;
}
```